# Thread.sleep behaving weirdly

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-sleep

I have the following code:

```
public Move chooseMove(Board board) {

    // start parallel thread
    this.tn = new TreeNode(this.myboard, this, null);
    tn.stop = false;
    this.curT = (new Thread(tn));
    this.curT.start();


    try {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread.sleep(4000 );
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        tn.stop=true;
        return getBestMove();
    }
}
```

The output is sometimes a value that is way greater than 4000ms like 5400ms which means that the thread is sleeping more than it should. Any help?
Thanks.

EDIT:
I understand that there is NO guarantee of Thread#sleep stoping precisely after the specified delay. However, an additional 1400ms is a long delay. Basically,I am implementing a game player agent and I need a way to run a task and then return a value to the server after 5s (or else the server ends the game). The server is using java.util.Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay). There is only one thread running concurent to the main thread which is this.curT in the code above, so there is ins't really heavy multithreading.

Comment: Is the processor very busy doing other things?  If the processor was really thrashing, with a lot of concurrent thread activity, a thread could not get cycles for a while.

Comment: How often do you get this behaviour? Try to run just your thread with sleep call without any else code.

Comment: If I run Thread.sleep alone in a single thread then it behaves correctly. but I have only 2 threads running in my real code as shown above

Answer (score 2):

From [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html):

> Two overloaded versions of sleep are provided: one that specifies the sleep time to the millisecond and one that specifies the sleep time to the nanosecond. However, these **sleep times are not guaranteed to be precise**, because they are limited by the facilities provided by the underlying OS. Also, the sleep period can be terminated by interrupts, as we'll see in a later section. In any case, **you cannot assume that invoking sleep will suspend the thread for precisely the time period specified**.

Comment: Yes but in my experience it does @Vito.   Any explanation about why it waiting for an additional 1400ms?

Comment: 1400ms is a long time - but activity such as a Garbage Collection could account for that. The bottom line, though, is that the pause time in Thread.sleep cannot be relied upon to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This is common behavior  and it is described in [`Thread#sleep`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) javadoc:

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, **subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers**.

Based on this, there's no guarantee of `Thread#sleep` stoping the work of the thread by the amount of milliseconds stated in the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`Thread#sleep` will make your thread sleep for **exactly** 4 seconds and then wake up.
Once your thread has woken up the OS scheduler places it in the *runnable* queue.
When it is next picked by the scheduler it will become a *running* thread i.e. will occupy the CPU.
So there is an additional delay overhead due to the OS scheduler which can vary per OS, system load etc. This is unrelated to `Java`

Comment: Is there a way to make the thread become running after exactly 4 seconds by influencing the OS scheduler runnable queue priorities?

Comment: You could assign `MAX_PRIORITY` but it is still not guaranteed to get the exact level of precision you seem to expect.If you need exactly 4 seconds you should do polling instead of `sleep`.With `sleep` you give up the CPU and there is no guarantee that you will get it back in 4 seconds. It is guaranteed that your thread will *wake up* in 4 seconds, but nothing else.

Comment: what do you mean by "polling"?

Comment: `while(true){if(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 4000) break}`

Comment: I tried that, but If the check is done at say [System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime = 3990] then it will go over 4000ms if the code inside the loop takes a long time ( which it shouldn't do but I have multiple threads running so I assume that may be the cause)

Comment: @Mouhyi:You are supposed to stall *after* you have done the processing so that the processing does not add up to the stalling time. I.e. do work and then spin-loop for 4 seconds. **UNLESS** you are you saying that you need the work to last for exactly 4 seconds